# Check if a function uses a specific keyword argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, python-decorators

I've got a decorator like this:

```
def auth(func):
    def dec(self, *args):
        user = Auth.auth(self.server.parse_params(), self.server.client_address)
        // snip...
        if user is None:
            raise NoSuchUserError
        func(self, *args, user=user)
    return dec
```

That works great, now I can write functions like this:

```
@auth
def serve_account(self, user=None):
    return json.dumps(user)
```

But sometimes I've got functions where I don't actually read the `user` parameter at all, I just want the decorator to take care of unauthenticated users. Take this as an example:

```
@auth
def serve_status(self, user=None):
    // I get the status here but I don't use the user parameter.
    return json.dumps(status)
```

Now my IDE and my static code analysis service keep nagging about it:

> Unused argument 'user'

It might also confuse people who don't know what's going on in the decorator:

```
TypeError: serve_status() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

I can't remove the parameter, otherwise I'll get a runtime error once the function gets called by the decorator.

Is there any way I can omit the parameter in the decorator if the function doesn't have it in the argument list? (Apart from creating a second decorator like `@auth_but_dont_pass_the_user`)

Comment: By "I don't use the user parameter" do you mean you're not using it in anywhere in function body or something else?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, that's exactly what I meant to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse to source of the function being called and check how many times the `user` variable is being used, if it is greater than 1 then you can call that function with the variable `user`:

```
import ast
import inspect


def is_variable_used(func, variable):
    source = inspect.getsource(func).split('\n', 1)[1]  # Split to drop the decorator part
    return sum(node.id == variable for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(source))
               if isinstance(node, ast.Name)) > 1


def auth(func):
    def dec(self, *args):
        if is_variable_used(func, 'user'):
            print 'Calling {func_name} with user.'.format(func_name=func.__name__)
            return func(self, user=100)
        else:
            print 'Calling {func_name} without user.'.format(func_name=func.__name__)
            return func(self)
    return dec


@auth
def func1_with_user(foo, user=None):
    return 10 + user

@auth
def func2_with_user(foo, user=None):
    a = 10 + foo
    b = a + foo
    c = a + b + user
    return a + b + c

@auth
def func1_without_user(foo, user=None):
    pass

@auth
def func2_without_user(foo, user=None):
    return 10 + foo


print func1_with_user(10)
print func2_with_user(20)
print func1_without_user(100)
print func2_without_user(200)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> !python so.py
Calling func1_with_user with user.
110
Calling func2_with_user with user.
260
Calling func1_without_user without user.
None
Calling func2_without_user without user.
210
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `**kwargs`? An example is this:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'user' in kwargs:
        print 'the given user is:', kwargs['user']
    else:
        # do something else
```

This way you don't have to explicitly put the parameter in the decorator, but you are able to retrieve it if the user specifies it.

Comment: Well, I *could* do that, but wouldn't that be even more confusing to look at?

Comment: @JohannBauer: No, this is really standard python and what is suggested to use when you want to allow optional parameters. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another)